# .GetSaveAsFilename dialog opens in background

Tags: excel, vbscript, secure-crt

I did a script which saves an excel-file where the user wants to save it. I am using `ExcelApplication.GetSaveAsFilname` for this.

Now my problem is: This "Save-Dialog" opens behind all other windows (main-problem is that it opens behind SecureCRT where I need this script).

Please help.

Code snippet:

```
strPath = app.GetSaveAsFilename("output","Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx, All Files (*.*),*.*", , "Save as") 
    If strPath = False Then 
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Where is the script running? How do you start the script?

Comment: SecureCRT - Script - Run

Comment: Only a program in the foreground can set the foreground window.

Comment: Is Excel visible when you call that method?  If not, call `app.Visible = True` beforehand, and ensure Excel is not minimized with `app.WindowState = -4143`.  If you know the app name (title) or process ID of your Excel app, then try calling `With CreateObject("WScript.Shell") : .AppActivate "Excel" : End With` beforehand.  If all else fails, [call Win32 APIs indirectly with PowerShell through VBScript](https://gist.github.com/codeartery/0ea3a74e92d39ce520cffb05a8b99446).  HTH.

Comment: Also, in SecureCRT, ensure the "Bring console window to front" checkbox is unchecked under Preferences > General.